# Wolfram Alpha: Simple Arithmetic with named constants replacement

Tags: arithmetic, wolfram-alpha

I want to verify an equation I implemented in a computer programming language using WA. For example:

> $\frac{s^2}{((s+w_0)(s+w_1))}$

And specify values for $s, w_0,$ and $w_1$.

I have tried:

> $\frac{s^2}{((s+w_0)(s+w_1))}$ where $s=2,w_0=4,w_1=8$

I would expect the answer to be $2/30$. But WA is doing something else.

The actual equation and constants are much more complex, and this feels like a slam dunk for WA if I use the correct syntax.

[Link to wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s%5E2%2F((s%2Bw0)*(s%2Bw1))%20where%20s%3D2,w0%3D4,w1%3D8)

Comment: Did you meant $$\frac{s^2}{(s+w_0)(s+w_1)}$$?

Comment: Yes, that is the equation.

Comment: Try [`s^2 / ( (s+w_0)*(s+w_1) ), s=2, w_0=4, w_1=8`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s%5E2+%2F+(+(s%2Bw_0)*(s%2Bw_1)+),+s%3D2,+w_0%3D4,+w_1%3D8) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2F((x%2Ba)*(x%2Bb)),%20x%3D2,a%3D4,b%3D8) Usually you need to use different expressions for the variables in W\A as it thinks $s$ is something else, whereas $x$ is often used to solve equations etc.